# Android API - how get the car position (fixed to the road)?

Tags: gps, android, navigation

All the android.location classes receives best REAL position of the GPS.
Is that any way to get from Google navigation API the CAR position x,y - fixed (tighten, interpolated) to the closest road on the Google map?

Comment: How do you know if the google map data is as accurate as the gps signal?

Comment: Out in the Philippines, The Roads on Google Maps can be 50-60 meters off in some cases, I know, I ride a bike and it often shows me in the town and not on the road. The tracers cut a lot of corners, literally, as well. This will improve over time as more effort gets invested. Perhaps you might like to explain what you are trying to achieve in your question and someone may be able to offer you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If by "Google navigation API" you're referring to either the on-device [Android Location API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) or [Google Play Services location services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html), the answer is no,  there is no way to get the road (or position on the road) that is closest to a given location (including the device's real-time location).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/).

This however, requires that you send HTTP-requests, and thereby also that you have an available internet connection, but it seems like it is the only solution, if you don't want to code your own map system to replace Google Maps, and use any open data source, like [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), and create your own rendering system with OpenGL ES etc..

I believe that it is more suited for taking a bunch of coordinates you've passed, snap them to roads and visualize them on a map, after you've passed them, and not to update in real-time, but I'm not sure because I haven't tried it yet.
Hopefully it works good enough.

You can find a guide to get started [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap).

Good luck and happy coding!